# Is there a way to make selecting query faster?

Tags: performance, sql-server-2012, query-optimization, query-performance

I want to select multiple rows from multiple tables, one of them having billions of rows. It sometimes take 20 seconds and there are over thousands of users using it so it is pretty bad.

I looked into COLUMNSTORE and tried it in my local machine and the performance is x50 faster than usual! (note that I was clearing the cache to see the difference)

However, the downside is I can't update, insert and delete rows, which is being constantly done for that table with the billion rows.

Is there a way to optimize it? (Besides the (NOLOCK) dirty read, which security is not an issue btw)

There are already indexes in that table, but doesn't help.

Is there a way to perform BATCH EXECUTION (I see it does row execution)? Or any optimization advice?

Using Microsoft SQL Server 2012

Comment: Maybe the query itself can be optimized? Could you post that and the corresponding execution plan?

Answer (score 0):

When you get to the scale of billions of rows, you often need to take different approaches for handling the data.  Separating the content into multiple databases and storing on different machines might be more effective, however the design is considerably more complex.

An alternative is to consider using a combination of partitioned tables with a column-based index.  That way at least, you can stage the updated data for the partition and then swap the updated one for the existing one to perform updates.  See: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg492088.aspx#Update

An alternative is to consider using three tables: one that is static -- and is perhaps using column-based storage -- the other one dynamic, holding only recent updates and inserts, and the third holding just a list of deleted rows identified by the primary key.  You then have to   use a view to reconcile the content for queries.